# ¿Por qué los datos en mis arrays se sobre escriben?

Tags: c#, array, método

Resulta que tengo 2 metodos en una clase.

En el primer método despliega un conjunto de operaciones a realizar, captura que operación quiere el usuario, los datos y realiza la operación.

Quiero enviar el numero de operación que escogió, los números que ingreso así como el resultado al segundo método, el cual después utilizaré para crear un xml o archvivo Excel, sin embargo al hacer una impresión de prueba de los vectores noté que se sobre escriben los datos y no sé como resolverlo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OperacionesMatrices
{
    class Opciones
    {
        int respMenuNum;
        int cont = 0;
        double num1, num2, result;
        String respSalir;
        private String rMenu;
        public String _rMenu
        {
            set { this.rMenu = value; }

            get { return this.rMenu; }
        }
       public void menu()
        {
            do
            {
                //Despliega el menu de opciones
                cont += 1;
                String Opcion;
                Console.WriteLine("Menu de operaciones :\n ");
                Console.WriteLine(" 1.- Suma");
                Console.WriteLine(" 2.- Resta");
                Console.WriteLine(" 3.- Multiplicación");
                Console.WriteLine(" 4.- División");
                Console.WriteLine(" 5.- Obtener el Residuo");
                Console.WriteLine(" Recuerda que los resultados serán almacenados");
                Console.Write("NOTA: Selecciona tu operación mediante el numero escrito con LETRA : ");
                Opcion = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                this.rMenu = Opcion;//Asigna el valor recibido a rMenu
                //transforma el valor recibido string en una nueva variable con tipo int para utilizar en el switch
                if (rMenu == "uno" || rMenu == "UNO")
                {
                    respMenuNum = 1;

                }
                else if (rMenu == "dos" || rMenu == "DOS")
                {
                    respMenuNum = 2;
                }
                else if (rMenu == "tres" || rMenu == "TRES")
                {
                    respMenuNum = 3;
                }
                else if (rMenu == "cuatro" || rMenu == "CUATRO")
                {
                    respMenuNum = 4;
                }
                else if (rMenu == "cinco" || rMenu == "CINCO")
                {
                    respMenuNum = 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    respMenuNum = 6;

                }

                //Realiza la operación que selecciono
                switch (respMenuNum)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Has seleccionado la opción " + rMenu + " se realizará la Suma");
                        Console.Write("Escribe el primer numero: ");
                        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Escribe el segundo numero: ");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        result = num1 + num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("De la suma del numero " + num1 + " más el numero " + num2 + " el resultado es: " + result);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Has seleccionado la opción " + rMenu + " se realizará la Resta");
                        Console.Write("Escribe el primer numero: ");
                        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Escribe el segundo numero: ");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        result = num1 - num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("De la resta del numero " + num1 + " menos el numero " + num2 + " el resultado es: " + result);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Has seleccionado la opción " + rMenu + " se realizará la Multiplicación");
                        Console.Write("Escribe el primer numero: ");
                        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Escribe el segundo numero: ");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        result = num1 * num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("De la multiplicación del numero " + num1 + " por el numero " + num2 + " el resultado es: " + result);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Has seleccionado la opción " + rMenu + " se realizará la es División");
                        Console.Write("Escribe el primer numero: ");
                        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Escribe el segundo numero: ");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        result = num1 / num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("De la división del numero " + num1 + " entre el numero " + num2 + " el resultado es: " + result);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Has seleccionado la opción " + rMenu + " se obtendrá el residuo de la división");
                        Console.Write("Escribe el primer numero: ");
                        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Escribe el segundo numero: ");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        result = num1 % num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("De la división del numero "+ num1+ " entre el numero "+num2 +" el residuo resultante es: " + result);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un numero dentro de los parametros establecidos");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Contador: " + cont);//imprime contador
                Console.WriteLine("Deseas hacer otra vez la operación? (S/N) ");
                respSalir= Console.ReadLine();
                arreglos(rMenu, num1, num2, result, cont);//envia el tipo de operación, el numero1, numero 2, resultado y el contador para almacenar en vectores


            } while (respSalir== "s" || respSalir== "S");//prosigue el ciclo o no


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void arreglos(String Opci, double numero1,double numero2, double resultado,int contador)
        {
            //String op;
            //double n1, n2, re;
            //op = Opci; n1 = numero1;n2 = numero2;re = resultado;
            String[] arrayOpe = new String[contador];
            double[] nume1 = new double[contador];
            double[] nume2 = new double[contador];
            double[] resu = new double[contador];
            //Recibe los datos y los almacena
            for (int x = 0; x < contador; x++)
            {
                arrayOpe[x] = Opci;
                nume1[x] = numero1;
                nume2[x] = numero2;
                resu[x] = resultado;


            }
            for (int x = 0; x < contador;x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vectores en la posición " + x + " Operación " + arrayOpe[x] + " Numero 1 fue: " + nume1[x] + " Numero 2 fue: " + nume2[x] + " con un resultado de: " + resu[x]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu método `arreglos` estás guardando los valores en la instancia `double[] nume1...` esto quiere decir que cada vez que llamas al método `arreglos`, el arreglo de doubles (por ejemplo) estaría vacío; si quieres mantener los valores de los arreglos, debes declararlos fuera del método `arreglos`, pero **no se si esa es la mejor práctica`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareceria ser que todo tu problema radica en la funcion arreglos

```
public void arreglos(String Opci, double numero1,double numero2, double resultado,int contador)
        {
            //String op;
            //double n1, n2, re;
            //op = Opci; n1 = numero1;n2 = numero2;re = resultado;
            String[] arrayOpe = new String[contador]; //estas creando un nuevo array cada vez q entras.
            double[] nume1 = new double[contador]; //y estos array para que son?
            double[] nume2 = new double[contador];
            double[] resu = new double[contador];
            //Recibe los datos y los almacena
            for (int x = 0; x < contador; x++)
            {
                arrayOpe[x] = Opci;
                nume1[x] = numero1;
                nume2[x] = numero2;
                resu[x] = resultado;
                //opci y las otras variables siempre tienen el valor con el que se entro a la funcion, solo vas a ver lo ultimo que se ingreso, en todo el array.

            }
            for (int x = 0; x < contador;x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vectores en la posición " + x + " Operación " + arrayOpe[x] + " Numero 1 fue: " + nume1[x] + " Numero 2 fue: " + nume2[x] + " con un resultado de: " + resu[x]);

            }
        }
```

Fijate que agregue comentarios a tu codigo.

Deberias declarar un array dinamico afuera de esta funcion, y utilizarlo en ella contra la posicion que diga cont.

Comment: Los arrays que me preguntas según yo son para almacenar los números que se utilizaron en las operaciones así como su resultado, mi idea era declarar una matriz de 3 dimensiones donde pudiera quedara algo así:

| Primer num ingresado|Segundo num ingresado|Resultado|
| Primer num ingresado|Segundo num ingresado|Resultado|

Pero no supe como meter distintas variables a la misma matriz, entonces decidí hacer 3 arreglos distintos para imprimirlos en conjunto

Entonces el array debo declararlo fuera del método? y como le paso los valores que envíe del método opciones?

Comment: sabes trabajar con objetos?? podrias declarar un objeto que guarde todos esos datos, y una array (o lista, o coleccion o con lo que sepas trabajar) que guarde objetos de esa clase.. y te ahorras todos los lios que te estas haciendo ahora...

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia con objetos pero haré la lucha, muchas gracias!

Comment: ok. si esta pregutna esta cerrada por favor acepta una respuesta, y si volves a tener dudas sigue consultado o ven al chat. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre inicias x = 0, por eso siempre los datos se guardan en  `arrayOpe[0]` sin importar el número de datos que tengas, para solucionarlo cambialo por lo siguiente

```
for (int x = contador-1; x < contador; x++)
        {
            arrayOpe[x] = Opci;
            nume1[x] = numero1;
            nume2[x] = numero2;
            resu[x] = resultado;


        }
```

Para esto no tendrías que definir `arrayOpe[]` ni ningún array como variable local, sino globales, es decir fuera de tu método, cada que ingreses un dato crear un array local con uno más de espacio, llenarlo con el array global, añadir el nuevo elemento y redeclarar tu array global con el local. Para este tipo de situaciones te convendría más las listas que los arrays.